# Search an replace text in column for Column Type Text SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, text-manipulation

What I need is to search for a string in a specific column (datatype: `text`) of a table and replace it with another text.

For example

```
Id          |          Text
-----------------------------
1                   this is test
2                   that is testosterone
```

If I chose to replace test with quiz, results should be

```
this is quiz
that is quizosterone
```

What I've tried so far?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SearchAndReplace] 
(
     @FindString    NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@ReplaceString NVARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT CONTENT_ID as id, CONTENT_TEXT, textptr(CONTENT_TEXT) as ptr, datalength(CONTENT_TEXT) as lng
 INTO #newtable6  FROM HTML_CONTENTS 
    DECLARE @COUNTER INT = 0
    DECLARE @TextPointer VARBINARY(16) 
    DECLARE @DeleteLength INT 
    DECLARE @OffSet INT 

    SELECT @TextPointer = TEXTPTR(CONTENT_TEXT)
      FROM #newtable6

    SET @DeleteLength = LEN(@FindString) 
    SET @OffSet = 0
    SET @FindString = '%' + @FindString + '%'

    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM #newtable6
            WHERE PATINDEX(@FindString, CONTENT_TEXT) <> 0) > 0
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @OffSet = PATINDEX(@FindString, CONTENT_TEXT) - 1
          FROM #newtable6
         WHERE PATINDEX(@FindString, CONTENT_TEXT) <> 0

UPDATETEXT #newtable6.CONTENT_TEXT
            @TextPointer
            @OffSet
            @DeleteLength
            @ReplaceString

           SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
    END
    select @COUNTER,* from #newtable6
drop table #newtable6
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

I get the error:

> Msg 7116, Level 16, State 4, Procedure SearchAndReplace, Line 31
>   Offset 1900 is not in the range of available LOB data.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datatype `TEXT` is **[deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)** and should not be used anymore - exactly because it's clunky and doesn't support all the usual string manipulation methods.

From the MSDN docs on text, ntext, image:

> *ntext, text, and image data types will
>   be removed in a future version of
>   MicrosoftSQL Server. **Avoid using these
>   data types** in new development work,
>   and plan to modify applications that
>   currently use them. **Use nvarchar(max),
>   varchar(max), and varbinary(max)
>   instead**.*

My recommendation: convert that column to VARCHAR(MAX) and you should be fine after that!

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.HTML_CONTENTS 
   ALTER COLUMN CONTEXT_TEXT VARCHAR(MAX)
```

That should do it.

When your column is `VARCHAR(MAX)`, then your stored procedures becomes totally simple:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SearchAndReplace] 
(@FindString    VARCHAR(100),
 @ReplaceString VARCHAR(100) )
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE dbo.HTML_CONTENTS
   SET CONTENT_TEXT = REPLACE(CONTEXT_TEXT, @FindString, @ReplaceString)
END
```

Two observations on the side:

- it would be helpful to have a `WHERE` clause in your stored proc, in order not to update the whole table (unless that's what you really need to do)
- you're using `TEXT` in your table, yet your stored procedure parameters are of type `NVARCHAR` - try to stick to **one** set - either `TEXT/VARCHAR(MAX)` and regular `VARCHAR(100)` parameters, or then use all Unicode strings: `NTEXT/NVARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(100)`. Constantly mixing those non-Unicode and Unicode strings is a mess and causes lots of conversions and unnecessary overhead

Comment: I can't convert it to varchar because the content is just too big for it. I know that replace is much more easier but this is what I have to do, I have to use UPDATETEXT for sure but thanks

Comment: @Pabuc: VARCHAR(MAX) can hold **up to 2 GByte** of text !! That's over 300 times the contents of Tolstoj's `War and Peace` - that **ought** to be enough even for your needs !!

Comment: Ok, after reading, I learned that it is big enough for my data but still, can't change it. This is a working application and just need to change a 2 word string with another string for the config table. Don't want to change them manually so now here I am :)

Comment: Also marc, I want to update every row that has @FindString in it. For my example, it should work since it is in a while loop. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Pabuc: my recommendation: stop wasting your time trying to figure out how to do it with TEXT / text pointers and all those kludges - just **change** it and be happy !

Comment: Would it cause any other problems (reading/writing) or can I change it with no doubts? :) thanks again

Comment: @Pabuc: in my experience, I never saw any problems with changing away from TEXT. Of course, any stored proc that does this messy textpointer kludge needs to be changed - but all new versions tend to be **a lot** simpler and nicer to use. **OF COURSE:** try this on a **test** environment first! But I've never seen any problem, really - the new VARCHAR(MAX) behaves just like any other VARCHAR column, and supports **ALL** usual string functions - that's the way it should have been from the start, really....

Comment: And don't ignore the fact that text is deprecated. It will not be available in the next version of SQL server. Start changing everything now.

Answer (score 5):

If you can't change your column types permanently, you can cast them on the fly:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SearchAndReplace] 
(@FindString    VARCHAR(100),
 @ReplaceString VARCHAR(100) )
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE dbo.HTML_CONTENTS
   SET CONTENT_TEXT = cast (REPLACE(cast (CONTEXT_TEXT as varchar(max)), @FindString, @ReplaceString) as TEXT)
END
```

Comment: Wish I could accept 2 answers since your answer actually works with the existing table structure :) thank you

Comment: @Pabuc, but changing that structure should be a very high priority. What you have now will NOT work with the next version of SQL Server.